# Bind and unbind button click event in JQuery

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I want to disable and enable a click event of the button after clicking it. Hide and show works. Unbind also works but rebinding does not works. Once the button is disabled it cannot be clicked again. What am i doing wrong here?

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="icon icon-repeat" aria-hidden="$test.get("test")},${test.get("group")}">
    <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

My script is below. I want to re enable the click event after I successfully receive the response:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.icon-repeat').on('click', function () {
        console.log("The button is clicked")
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '${createLink(action: 'test')}',
            data: {test: test},
            dataType: 'text',
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('.flashMessage').html(response);

            },
            fail: function (response) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `bind()` or `unbind()`. They were deprecated a while ago. Use `on()` and `off()` instead.

Your actual issue is that you're attempting to create an event handler without specifying what logic should be executed under that event.

A better way to approach this would be to define the logic in its own function which can be added/removed in a much easier manner:

```js
function iconRepeatHandler() {
  $('.icon-repeat').off('click');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '${createLink(action: 'testAction')}',
    data: {
      test: test
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(response) {
      $('.icon-repeat').on('click', iconRepeatHandler);
    },
    fail: function(response) {}
  });
}

$('.icon-repeat').on('click', iconRepeatHandler);
```

Comment: How can i call this function in button Click event?

Comment: Please let me know your resource of knowledge.I will read from there too. Amazed by your answers and depth explanation you gave...........+1

Comment: @jennysam `$('.icon-repeat').on('click', iconRepeatHandler);` this line (repeated on load and in the AJAX callback) is what attaches the click handler.

Comment: can you edit your answer according to my implementation/

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank you, that's very kind of you to say.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  really you have greate knowledge of javascript/jQuery. If you have any good resource for that let me know. I will seriously follow that resource.

Comment: I just read the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript). Then it's a case of understanding the best patterns to follow in a given situation - that just comes with experience.

Comment: Rory McCrossan..The iconRepeatHandler() is not called now..How can i do that?

Comment: You must have an error somewhere else in your page as this works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q5co7ejw/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Rory's answer, there is another approach which you can try. Toggle the classes and based on that bind the event handler:

```js
$('.icon-repeat.active').on('click', function () {
    console.log("The button is clicked")
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.removeClass("active");
    // document.getElementById("btnSubmit").hidden = true
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '${createLink(action: 'testAction')}',
        data: {test: test},
        dataType: 'text',
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (response) {
                elem.addClass("active");
            // document.getElementById("btnSubmit").hidden = false
        },
        fail: function (response) {
        }
    });
});
```

Bind the event only to those elements which has `active` `and icon-repeat` class. In the handler, remove the `active` class and in success add that again.

Comment: @jennysam yes, that's a classname

Comment: Click function is executed only if there is $('.icon-repeat').on('click', function ()  not $('.icon-repeat.active').on('click', function ()

Comment: @jennysam If you can modify your code to add active class, then it will work

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: @jennysam add active class to the element in the html

Comment: you mean class="icon icon-repeat active"